# getrequestURL of the parent frame

Tags: java, javascript, html, css, jsp

i need to write a jsp code to get getRequestURL() of the Parent frame (URL in the address bar) from a child frame. When i try to do this i get the URL of the child frame. Can some one help me in getting that from child frame.

```
 <% String s=request.getRequestURL().toString();
 out.println(s);
 if(s.contains("Password"))
 {
 out.println("Password changed Successfully");
 }
 %>
```

Answer (score 0):

> i need to write a jsp code to get getRequestURL() of the Parent frame

That wasn't the URL requested in order to get the page you are sending back. It was the URL requested to get (essentially) a link to that page.

You could look at the Referer header. Note that defined as being optional, it is often blocked and sometimes contains false information.